# Sketch JS, how to use AWS pre-signed URL on audio tag?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, url, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

**Quick look**

> I'm using [Sketch.js](https://github.com/soulwire/sketch.js) plugin in [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZpzYWq) example. I
>   would like to use my pre-signed urls as well but they don't work.
>   Expiration time is set long enough (1 day) so there's something wrong
>   with the JS itself.

I have an S3 bucket where I store some music public protected. 
Using the official AWS SDK I can generate urls like:

`https://d225******.cloudfront.net/song.m4a?Expires=1493381986&Signature=***&Key-Pair-Id=***`

I'm using pre-signed urls over my website without any problem, but in this script won't work:

```
<script>
var ALPHA, AudioAnalyser, COLORS, MP3_PATH, NUM_BANDS, NUM_PARTICLES, Particle, SCALE, SIZE, SMOOTHING, SPEED, SPIN;

MP3_PATH = 'my_presigned_url';

AudioAnalyser = (function() {
  AudioAnalyser.AudioContext = self.AudioContext || self.webkitAudioContext;

  AudioAnalyser.enabled = AudioAnalyser.AudioContext != null;

  function AudioAnalyser(audio, numBands, smoothing) {
    var src;
    this.audio = audio != null ? audio : new Audio();
    this.numBands = numBands != null ? numBands : 256;
    this.smoothing = smoothing != null ? smoothing : 0.3;
    if (typeof this.audio === 'string') {
      src = this.audio;
      this.audio = new Audio();
      this.audio.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
      this.audio.controls = true;
      this.audio.src = src;
    }
    this.context = new AudioAnalyser.AudioContext();
    this.jsNode = this.context.createScriptProcessor(2048, 1, 1);
    this.analyser = this.context.createAnalyser();
    this.analyser.smoothingTimeConstant = this.smoothing;
    this.analyser.fftSize = this.numBands * 2;
    this.bands = new Uint8Array(this.analyser.frequencyBinCount);
    this.audio.addEventListener('canplay', (function(_this) {
      return function() {
        _this.source = _this.context.createMediaElementSource(_this.audio);
        _this.source.connect(_this.analyser);
        _this.analyser.connect(_this.jsNode);
        _this.jsNode.connect(_this.context.destination);
        _this.source.connect(_this.context.destination);
        return _this.jsNode.onaudioprocess = function() {
          _this.analyser.getByteFrequencyData(_this.bands);
          if (!_this.audio.paused) {
            return typeof _this.onUpdate === "function" ? _this.onUpdate(_this.bands) : void 0;
          }
        };
      };
    })(this));

  }

  AudioAnalyser.prototype.start = function() {
    return this.audio.play();
  };

  AudioAnalyser.prototype.stop = function() {
    return this.audio.pause();
  };

  return AudioAnalyser;

})();

Sketch.create({
  particles: [],
  setup: function() {
    var analyser, error, i, intro, j, particle, ref, warning, x, y;
    for (i = j = 0, ref = NUM_PARTICLES - 1; j <= ref; i = j += 1) {
      x = random(this.width);
      y = random(this.height * 2);
      particle = new Particle(x, y);
      particle.energy = random(particle.band / 256);
      this.particles.push(particle);
    }
    if (AudioAnalyser.enabled) {
      try {
        analyser = new AudioAnalyser(MP3_PATH, NUM_BANDS, SMOOTHING);
        analyser.onUpdate = (function(_this) {
          return function(bands) {
            var k, len, ref1, results;
            ref1 = _this.particles;
            results = [];
            for (k = 0, len = ref1.length; k < len; k++) {
              particle = ref1[k];
              results.push(particle.energy = bands[particle.band] / 256);
            }
            return results;
          };
        })(this);
        analyser.start();
        document.getElementById('player-container').appendChild(analyser.audio);
        document.getElementsByTagName("audio")[0].setAttribute("id", "dy_wowaudio"); 
        intro = document.getElementById('intro');
        intro.style.display = 'none';
      } catch (_error) {
        error = _error;
      }
    }
  }
});
// generated by coffee-script 1.9.2
</script>
```

The script works fine (as you can see in the example above) without a pre-signed url, so **what can I do to use my pre-signed urls inside `AudioAnalyser` function**?

Comment: You need to find an error message, somewhere... perhaps in the HTTP response headers.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot from console I get `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.` And from the network tab I get `Status Code:206 get from server AmazonS3 miss from Cloudfront`

Comment: Questions.  `206` means you asked for and received only partial content, which means you're apparently going to make multiple requests... and implies (but doesn't prove) that this request is not the first one made and might not have been the last.  How far into the future did you set `Expires`?  If you disable the requirement for signed URLs and make it so an object in the same bucket can simply be downloaded through CloudFront with no signature, does that work?  It's not clear if that is exactly what you meant when you said it works with a "normal URL."

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Expiration is set to 1 day. I can play the song in another page (in an audio tag) without [this](http://soulwire.github.io/sketch.js/) script. This is a full working [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZpzYWq?editors=1010) with a normal url (not pre-signed).

Comment: the codepen expample didn't want to load for me. sketch.min.js failed with "(blocked:mixed-content)". Switching to the cdnjs hosted copy got it working. (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sketch.js/1.0/sketch.min.js)

Comment: @JohnJones I don't know why, in my case it works. Anyway it's not related to my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen html5 video tags make multiple requests. I assume to fetch some meta-data like play length and the first frame of video to use as a thumbnail. You might try playing with the preload attribute to prevent this.

Specifically, if the clip is small, `preload="auto"` might be everything you need. If the browser has to make follow requests you're gonna have a hard time I think. [Here's some relevant info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio)

Another way to go about this that I think may work more reliably is to generate temporary credentials as needed.

See the docs for more on this:
- [Requesting temp creds](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp_request.html)
- [Accessing resources with temp creds](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp_use-resources.html#RequestWithSTS)

Combined with a JS package for signing AWS requests like [binoculars/aws-sigv4](https://github.com/binoculars/aws-sigv4) or [copy someone else](https://github.com/Liath/aws-request-signer/) who's doing this in-browser.

Answer (score -2):

Share your browser error message if any. It may by problem related to cross origin for S3 bucket data.

Comment: as I said the url works fine with pre-signed, there's a problem with this script. From log from console I get Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.

Comment: Ok, This is Uncauch in Promiss exception. Write Method autoplay uncompatable browser executed the code like if (playPromise !== undefined) {
  playPromise.then(function() {
    // Automatic playback started!
  }).catch(function(error) {
    // Automatic playback failed.
    // Show a UI element to let the user manually start playback.
  });
}

Comment: if (AudioAnalyser.enabled) {
try{
}
catch{
write same code for manual play.
}

Comment: Nirmal, meta comment here: when you want to help but need more info, it's best to add a comment under the original question.